MudNumericField max decimal length
In Blazor Server net8,
I am trying to limit the number of decimal digits the user can input in <MudNumericField>
For example if I want to limit it to two(2) decimal digits, then the input field should ignore the next decimal input.
Though I still want to preserve the comma formatting for the whole number for the thousands place. i.e. 1,000.00
I have tried using Value and ValueChanged but it still allows the user to input, the excess decimal digits are only removed(truncated) if the numericField loses focus but it rounds off the value like 99.999 will become 100 when I want it to be 99.99, so I think preventing user input will be better
<MudNumericField @bind-Value="Allowance"
                 T="decimal"
                 Culture="@(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))"
                 Format="C2"
                 Min="0"
                 Immediate" />

private decimal Allowance { get; set; } = 0.0m;

I also tried OnKeyPress, OnKeyDown, and OnKeyUp, but still does not behave the way I expect it since there is a split second where it appends the input, then quickly removes it, but I may be doing it wrong
private void OnKeyUpEvent(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    string allowanceString = Allowance.ToString("G29", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    int decimalIndex = allowanceString.IndexOf('.');

    if (decimalIndex >= 0 && allowanceString.Length - decimalIndex - 1 > 10)
    {
        allowanceString = allowanceString.Substring(0, decimalIndex + 11);

        if (decimal.TryParse(allowanceString, out var truncatedAllowance))
        {
            Allowance = truncatedAllowance;
        }
    }
}


This requirement can be achieved by listening to the input in native JavaScript language, and here is my sample code and test results.
Test Result

TestPage.razor
@page "/test"
@using System.Globalization
@using MudBlazor
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<MudTextField T="string"
              @bind-Value="AllowanceString"
              Label="Allowance"
              Immediate="true"
              InputType="InputType.Text"
              InputAttributes="inputAttributes"
              Id="allowanceInput"
              Style="width: 200px;" />

<p>Current Vaule：@Allowance</p>

@code {
    private decimal Allowance { get; set; } = 0.00m;

    private string AllowanceString
    {
        get => Allowance.ToString("#,0.00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        set
        {
            var sanitizedValue = value.Replace(",", "");
            if (decimal.TryParse(sanitizedValue, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var result))
            {
                Allowance = Math.Truncate(result * 100) / 100m;
            }
            else
            {
                Allowance = 0m;
            }
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, object> inputAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "oninput", "limitDecimalPlaces(this, 2)" }
    };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("addInputEvent", "#allowanceInput");
        }
    }
}

_Host.cshtml
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorApp1.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // addEventListener input  
        window.addInputEvent = function (selector) {
            var element = document.querySelector(selector);
            if (element) {
                element.addEventListener('input', function () {
                    limitDecimalPlaces(element, 2);
                });
            }
        };
    });

    function limitDecimalPlaces(element, decimalPlaces) {
        var value = element.value;

        value = value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '');

        var parts = value.split('.');
        if (parts.length > 2) {
            value = parts[0] + '.' + parts[1]; 
        }

        if (parts.length > 1 && parts[1].length > decimalPlaces) {
            alert("Tip: You can only enter up to "+decimalPlaces+" decimal places！");
            
            value = parts[0] + '.' + parts[1].substring(0, decimalPlaces);
        }

        element.value = value;
    }
</script>



</body>
</html>


Thank you for this, it works normally on a single input element, however, it does not seem to work when using it as a cell template for MudDataGrid since I am using it as a cell in the Allowance column, any workarounds for this? Thanks!

@HerOine Please share your sample code, I am willing to check it. And please don't hide your sensitive information if any.

Hello, sorry for the late response, I may have found the issue of the problem and may not be directly related to MudDataGrid, if you can check my cell template component snippet, the switch to IsOnEdit may be causing the issue of the element.addEventListener not applying to the element, since i tried to console log the element itself and it was null. is there a solution to this? thanks.
